# How do I change my StackExchange subscription email address?

Tags: support, email-notification

Recently I tend to use a new email address and want to change my SE subscription email address to that one. But could not found a way. Is there any option for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to [your profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/152562/gulshan) and click on the [edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/edit/152562) link near the top.

[image: Edit User Info]

You can edit all of your profile information, including your email address, from that page.  At the bottom of the page, you can copy that profile to all of your Stack Exchange accounts, and on the main Stack Exchange network profile page you can synch with your oldest account.

Comment: Wow, It was that easy. I merged two accounts and couldn't get rid of my old email address. Maybe this is a recent feature. A searched a lot and everyone said you couldn't update the original email address.