# How do I change my email address for logging in?

Tags: support, login

I see this has been asked multiple times, and there are several answers, most of which seem to be out of date.

I can't seem to find the screens on my profile page that they're referring to (is there more than one profile page?) and links to profile pages are broken.

What's the simplest way to change the email address, and preserve the username, all of the badges and reputations? That's all I want to do.

I don't have any other way of logging in, nor do I wish to (I'd really prefer not to have to create a dummy Facebook or Twitter account just to use as an intermediate step to changing my email, but if that's the simplest way...)

I know we aren't supposed to express opinions in questions, but it really is perplexing why something this simple has to be made this difficult. I can't imagine any security benefit to this.

[How can I change my Stack Exchange login email?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247605/how-can-i-change-my-stackexchange-login-email)

[How do I change my login provider(s)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers)

[How do I change the email address associated with my Stack Exchange OpenID?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102392/how-do-i-change-the-email-address-associated-with-my-stack-exchange-openid)

[How do I change my StackExchange subscription email address?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158821/how-do-i-change-my-stackexchange-subscription-email-address)

[How can I change my email on all sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211229/how-can-i-change-my-email-on-all-sites)

Comment: So... our email situation is a bit of a ... mess at the moment as different email settings are potentially used for different things. We're working on it, but in the meantime let's address your specific problem. What are you trying to do? Change the email you log in with? The address newsletters arrive at? Something else?

Comment: @AdamLear Thanks for the reply. The email account that I use to log in with still exists, but I am in the process of deleting it.  I just want to log in with a new email. I don't have newsletters set up at the moment. Thanks

Comment: Cool, fair enough. See my answer; I hope it helps. If you hit any snags, feel free to email me (the address is in my profile).

Comment: I totally agree with the OP's criticism.  This is too difficult for such a simple maintenance task.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, we don't have a very straightforward way to change the email associated with your login at the moment. The good news is that there's a few workarounds.

The first one is described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers).

The second is that you could register a new account with the new email and then use the "contact us" link at the bottom to merge it with your existing account.

There used to be a third way, but [support for it ended on July 25, 2018](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307647/support-for-openid-ended-on-july-25-2018). That way was to sign up for a new credential over at http://openid.stackexchange.com, and then use the instructions in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/280525) to attach it to your Q&A account.

So, go with whichever of the first two options is easier for you.

Comment: Excellent! That worked. I now have two logins, albeit with the same password, and I'll delete the first one after I have used the new one sucessfully a few times (never hurts to be cautious). Thanks.

Comment: I'm amazed that a site as good as stackexchange.com hasn't come up with a simple solution for this.